# PHP Built-in Webserver and Relative Paths

Tags: webserver, relative-path, php-5.4

### TL;DR

Does PHP 5.4 built-in webserver have any bug or restriction about relative paths? Or does it need to be properly (and additionally) configured?

---

When I used to programming actively I had a system working under URI routing using these lines in a **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ index.php [L]
```

The FrontController received the Request, find the proper route from given URI in a SQLITE database and the Dispatcher call the the Action Controller.

It worked very nicely with Apache. Today, several months later I decided to run my Test Application with PHP 5.4 built-in webserver.

First thing I noticed, obviously, **.htaccess** don't work so I used code file instead:

```
<?php

if( preg_match( '/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ) ) {
    return false;
}

include __DIR__ . '/index.php';
```

And started the webserver like this:

```
php.exe -c "php.ini" -S "localhost:8080" "path\to\testfolder\routing.php"
```

So far, so good. Everything my application need to bootstrap could be accomplished by modifying the *include_path* like this:

```
set_include_path(

    '.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . realpath( '../common/next' )
);
```

Being **next** the *core* folder of all modules inside a folder for with everything common to all applications I have. And it doesn't need any further explanation for this purpose.

None of the **AutoLoader** techniques I've ever saw was able to *autoload* themselves, so the only class manually required is my Autoloader. But after running the Test Application I received an error because my AutoLoader could not be found. o.O

I always was very suspicious about realpath() so I decided to change it with the full and absolute path of this **next** directory and it worked. It shouldn't be needed to do as I did, but it worked.

My autoloader was loaded and successfully registered by spl_autoload_register(). For the reference, this is the *autoloading* function (only the Closure, of course):

```
function( $classname ) {

    $classname = stream_resolve_include_path(

        str_replace( '\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $classname ) . '.php'
    );

    if( $classname !== FALSE ) {

        include $classname;
    }
};
```

However, resources located whithin *index.php* path, like the MVC classes, could not be found. So I did something else I also should not be doing and added the working directory to the *include_path*. And again, manually, without rely on realpath():

```
set_include_path(

    '.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'path/to/common/next'
        . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'path/to/htdocs/testfolder/'
);
```

And it worked again... Almost! >.<

The most of Applications I can create with this system works quite well with my Standard Router, based on SQLITE databases. And to make things even easier this Router looks for a predefined SQLITE file within the working directory.

Of course, I also provide a way to change this default entry just in case and because of this I check if this file exist and trigger an error if it doesn't.

And this is the specific error I'm seeing. The checking routine is like this:

```
if( ! file_exists( $this -> options -> dbPath ) ) {

    throw RouterException::connectionFailure(

       'Routes Database File %s doesn\'t exist in Data Directory',

       array( $this -> options -> dbPath )
    );
}
```

The **dbPath** entry, if not changed, uses a constant value **Data/Routes.sqlite**, relatively to working directory.

If, again, again, I set the absolute path manually, everything (really) works, the the Request flow reached the Action Controllers successfully.

What's going on?

Comment: Yop.. same problem here... (using php 5.3x)... the problem is in the PHP HTTP Server... if you try this just with a HTML app you'll get the same problem...

Comment: I noticed that if I run the batch script responsible to start the built-in webserver from within the directory where this relative path definition is, it sometimes works. Sometimes because depends on the application (phpMyAdmin didn't work). But this a terrible limitation as I can't run two different applications at once -OR- both webserver runs should listen two different ports. Worse! I would have several batch scripts, one per application while if without this bug, only one pointing to "." would be enough.

Comment: I'm not aware of any configuration directive to change this behavior. I still think that PHP's internal webserver misses the internal redirect. My bug report was instantly flagged as **not a bug**: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66191

Answer (score 1):

**This a bug in PHP's built-in web server** that is still not fixed, as of PHP version 5.6.30.

In short, the web server does not redirect to `www.foo.com/bar/` if `www.foo./bar` was requested and happens to be a directory. The client being server `www.foo.com/bar`, assumes it is a file (because of the missing slash at the end), so all subsequent relative links will be fetched relative to `www.foo.com/`instead of `www.foo.com/bar/`.

[A bug ticket was opened](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66191) back in 2013 but was mistakenly set to a status of "Not a Bug".

I'm experiencing a similar issue in 2017, so I left a comment on the bug ticket.

**Edit :** Just noticed that @jens-a-koch opened the ticket I linked to. I was not awar of his comment on the original question.